# Make an NSURL with an encoded plus (%2B)

Tags: iphone, url, html-encode

I need to pass a timestamp with a timezone offset in a GET request, e.g.,

> 2009-05-04T11:22:00+01:00

This looks like a two arguments "2009-05-04T11:22:00" and "01:00" to the receiving PHP script (over which I've no control).

NSURL doesn't encode plus signs, but if I make an NSURL using the string

> 2009-05-04T11:22:00%2B01:00

the url I end up with contains:

> 2009-05-04T11:22:00%252B01:00

Any ideas how I can preserve my encoded plus sign or just plain prevent NSURL from encoding anything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What worked for me was doing the UTF8 conversion, then replacing the + sign with %2B:

```
NSString *urlString =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/iphone/push/create?pn[token]=%@&pn[send_at]=%@",
     kHTTPURL, appDelegate.deviceAPNToken, [dateTimeToUse description]];

urlString =
    [[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is the correct answer. The questions asks how to create a proper NSURL object. If this string is used to create an NSURL object, the % sign will again be encoded as %25. Please clarify.

Comment: This solves the problem. However it is not the correct solution as it only deals with '+' and not other characters that need to be encoded.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead, I encoded the timestamp using Ric Santos's answer BEFORE creating the urlString. In my experience, I've never seen anyone need to encode the parameter names, schema, domain or other parts of a url. So, it is always best to encode the parameter values separately. But, it would be nice to have a function that would break apart a url, encoded it correctly, then put it back together. I assumed that stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding did this, but apparently it fails for cases like + signs.

Answer (score 3):

The string should be URL encoded.

Here is a category for NSString that will help:

**NSString+Additions.h**

```
@interface NSString (Additions)

- (NSString *)stringByURLEncoding;
```

**NSString+Additions.m**

```
#import "NSString+Additions.h"

@implementation NSString (Additions)

- (NSString *)stringByURLEncoding {
    return (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)self,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                           CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSString`'s `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method on the text you want to include as an argument.

As its name implies, the method will convert return an auto-released string containing an url-safe version of the receiver.

Comment: I tried that - it converts '+' to '%2B'. NSURL then encodes the '%' so you end up with '%252B'

Comment: Most probably, you're doing something wrong with the URL then. You need to use NSURL's `URLWithString:`.

Comment: And make sure you're not calling that method twice on the same string, otherwise it <em>will</em> call it encode your resulting string twice, thus encoding the % into a %25. Also make sure you're using NSUTF8Encoding everywhere.

Comment: It just plain doesn't work. The '+' character is perfectly valid in URLs and won't be encoded by NSURL. If you leave it in, it appears as a separate argument.
In the end, I had to convert the timestamp to GMT and remove the timezone offset from the string. Not pretty, but there's other stuff to move on to...

Answer (score 2):

Thought I may as well provide my workaround as an answer, as I don't think there's a good solution to the original problem.

The plus sign (+) is completely valid in a URL, so my solution was to convert the time to GMT and remove the timezone/DST offset from the string. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to determine the value of *secondsFromGMT* below as, in my case, it's always the same because I'm only interested in timestamps generated by a web server.

```
NSString *gmtWhen = [[self descriptionWithCalendarFormat:nil
                           timeZone:[NSTimeZone
                           timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:secondsFromGMT
                     ] locale:nil] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +0000" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution when using **URLComponents** (Swift 3):

```
var params = ["email": "user+ios-default@example.com", "name": "John Brown"]
var components = URLComponents(string: "http://www.example.com")!
components.path = "/login"
components.queryItems = params.map { URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1) }

let url_NoFix = components.url!
// http://www.example.com/login?name=John%20Brown&email=user+ios-default@example.com

let cs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+").inverted
let q =  components.percentEncodedQuery?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: cs)
components.percentEncodedQuery = q

let url_Fixed = components.url!
// http://www.example.com/login?name=John%20Brown&email=user%2Bios-default@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

encode you string by using below code

NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, 
(CFStringRef)self,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"+",kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

this will encode + of you string which will prevent replacement of + by %2b while posting data in post method

Answer (score 0):

To get encoded plus (%2B) (It works with all charcters) use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`  as

```
/**
 get parameterized url from url and query parameters.
 */
+(NSString *)getParameterizedUrl:(NSString *)url withParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryDictionary
{
    NSMutableArray *mutablePairs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *key in queryDictionary) {
        [mutablePairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", CTPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding(key, NSUTF8StringEncoding), CTPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding(queryDictionary[key], NSUTF8StringEncoding)]];
    }

    return [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?%@",url,[mutablePairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]];
}

static NSString * const kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString = @":/?&=;+!@#$()',*";

static NSString * CTPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    static NSString * const kCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey = @"[].";

    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}

static NSString * CTPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

And use in your code as

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setObject:@"2009-05-04T11:22:00+01:00" forKey:@"timestamp"];

NSString *urlString = [self getParameterizedUrl:@"http://www.example.com" withParameters:params];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```