# How to pass '+' sign with url in iOS?

Tags: ios, url, urlencode

I need to pass some parameters from iOS system to the server.

one of those parameters is `timezone`, and I need to include the sign in front of the hour value like `+02:00`

I tried this:

```
let url = "http://my_server/my_page.php?timezone=+02:00"
let urlEncoded = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

But unfortunately didn't work. And at the server I got " " space instead of the "+" sign. (`PHP` used on the server)

I saw [Objective-C url encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086845/5559741) but really I don't need to encode `http://..`, I only need the `+` sign in the parameters list.

Also I look at [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url), But when I send `+` sign, `PHP` server will omit it.

Comment: use `%2B` instead of `+` sign.

Comment: Maybe answers for [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898488/make-an-nsurl-with-an-encoded-plus-2b) will be helpful.

Comment: You need to encode the query part of the url not the entire url, so you need to encode the query part first then compose the result into the url.

Comment: The way you need to use encoding functions depends on implementation of your networking client. In general it is possible to safely encode individual parameters, in your case only the part "+02:00" needs to be encoded.

Comment: Thanks all, @SunnyJain you can post your answer and I will accept it. Can you please put the `-` equivalent also ?

Comment: @wajeeh `-` is an unreserved character, it needn't be encoded. Check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for more detail.

Comment: @wajeeh : You can see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) `%2D` is used for `-`